# Delete Login details in WebView

Tags: c#, cookies, webview, xamarin.android

I am looking to remove all cookies from a WebView (Using Xamarin.Android) however currently on some sites user login information is retained.

I am currently utilizing

CookieManager.Instance.RemoveAllCookies(null)

And this works for most sites however on Some SSO sites or if example you create a base ASP.NET web application and enable Windows Auth and deploy to IIS. When navigating to the created site via a WebView and logging in. When I close the WebView and re open (The above RemoveAll is called) but the user does not have to re enter creds.

I have tried other methods along with the above such as

WebStorage.Instance.DeleteAllData();
and ClearCache(true)

However nothing seems to be clearing them.

Does anyone have any ideas?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

First, you need to define an interface like this:

```
public interface IDeviceSpecificService
{
    void ClearCookies();
}
```

Then use the code like this in Xamarin.Forms:

```
DependencyService.Get<IDeviceSpecificService>().ClearCookies();
```

In the Xamarin.Android

```
 public class DeviceSpecificService : IDeviceSpecificService
    {
        public void ClearCookies()
        {
            Android.Webkit.CookieManager.Instance.RemoveAllCookie();
        }
    }
```

In the Xamarin.IOS

```
public class DeviceSpecificService : IDeviceSpecificService
    {
        public void ClearCookies()
        {
              NSHttpCookieStorage CookieStorage = NSHttpCookieStorage.SharedStorage;
              foreach (var cookie in CookieStorage.Cookies)
                      CookieStorage.DeleteCookie(cookie);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thank you very much for responding Guangyu Bai.  The second example (Xamarin.Android) example is the one that I have implemented at the moment. (Also tried with RemoveAllCookies(null).  It works for the vast majority but just not on the examples I mentioned.

Comment: You can check the document [CookieManager Class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/android.webkit.cookiemanager?view=xamarin-android-sdk-13) for more information.